# How to plot bar graph for certain values from the column in ggplot2? Values will be selected automatically from the data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset containing 3 columns (Year, rain, temp) like below

```
  Year      tem     rain
1 1901 24.81962 202.7350
2 1902 24.67261 195.4762
3 1903 24.82354 188.1156
4 1904 24.62806 204.1724
5 1905 24.20550 233.8594
6 1906 24.78262 172.8214
```

Now, I want to plot a graph `temp` vs `year` but not all `year` values. For example, only `1910`,`1920` and so on.

After reading some post given in the `StackOverflow` I have written this code

```
plot_rain <- ggplot(subset(data=aggdata, Year %in% c("1901" , "1910")))+
             geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=tem, color=factor(Year)))+
  theme_minimal()+
  xlab("Year")+
  ylab("Temperature")+
  ggtitle("Temp according to Year") 
ggplotly(plot_rain)
```

It is showing `Error in Year %in% c("1901", "1910") : object 'Year' not found`

What I have to do to solve this problem? I searched `Google` `StackOverflow` but the problem and solutions seem different from mine!

However, is it possible to increase the value of `c()` automatically based on a range? Like, `1901, 1910, 1920, ...`

Answer (score 0):

The subset problem I can solve for you, although I'm not sure how you want to color each line by year, if year is your y-axis, so I removed this part:

```
plot_rain <- ggplot(data=aggdata[aggdata$Year %in% c(1901,1903,1905),])+
  geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=tem))+
  xlab("Year")+
  ylab("Temperature")+
  ggtitle("Temp according to Year")
```

[image]

### Update for discrete x-Axis

For a discrete x-Axis, we have to factor the Year Variable.

```
plot_rain <- ggplot(data=aggdata[aggdata$Year %in% c(1901,1903,1905),],
                    aes(x=factor(Year), y=tem)) +
  geom_line(group=1) +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Temperature") +
  ggtitle("Temp according to Year") 

plot_rain
```

The `subset` function you tried to use does something different. To select the years, just check the `aggdata$Year` column against the desired vector of years. Then the plotting works.
[image]

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But, I used Year in the x-axis. Why the graph is also showing 1902, 1904?

Comment: Your a-axis was continuous data. I updated it for a discrete values x-Axis

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to display the years you have selected, I am not sure if a line diagram is the best way to visualize your data. As the gaps in your data are connected with a line, one easily assumes that every point on your line represents (or estimates) a year. If you explicitely want to exclude years from your visualization, I would represent the data as a bar plot.

```
# init
"%>%" <- magrittr::"%>%"

# your data
dat <- dplyr::tibble(Year=1901:1906,
                     tem=c(24.81962,24.67261,24.82354,24.62806,24.20550,24.78262),
                     rain=c(202.7350,195.4762,188.1156,204.1724,233.8594,172.8214))

# define range for filtering years
min <- 1901
max <- 1904

# plot data: filter years between min, max 
# and transform year to factor (as you want a descrete x-axis)
dat %>%
dplyr::filter(dplyr::between(Year,min,max)) %>%
dplyr::mutate(Year=factor(Year)) %>%
ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=Year,y=tem,fill=Year)) + 
ggplot2::geom_bar(stat="identity") +
ggplot2::theme_minimal() + 
ggplot2::labs(title="Temp according to Year",
              x="Year",
              y="Temperature")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. Yes, I was wrong, I should plot a `Bar Graph`. However, in my actual dataset, I have a lot of data like from `1901 to 2000`. So, do I have to add them manually in the code? Also, I do not need to all year in the graph. Only need to plot some specific `year: 1901 than 10 years later`. Is it possible to do that in your code?

Comment: if you have ranges - 1901 plus the next 10 years - you could define `min <- 1901` and `max <- 1911`. This way you would only display these specific years. if you need something more complex and if you want to use your code inside a function. you could have a look into `non standard evaluation`. With NSE you could pass a complex filter as parameter to your function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also agree with @sambold, you should try `bar plot`.
However, I made some changes to the @Julian_Hn code.

```
plot_rain <- ggplot(data=aggdata[aggdata$Year %in% c(1901,1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950),], 
           aes(x=factor(Year), y=tem, fill=factor(Year)))+
           geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.5, group=1)+
           theme_minimal()+
           xlab("Year")+
           ylab("Temperature")+
          ggtitle("Temp according to Year") 
       ggplotly(plot_rain)
```

I have no idea, how you can do automatic increment value of `year`
[image: Plot]